# A square-squareroot integer race sequence involving primes

Tags: pr.probability, prime-numbers, discrete-mathematics, integer-sequences

I wonder what is the expected behavior of this process?

Let

> $f^2_{\mathrm{next}}(n) =$ the next prime after $n^2$.
>
> $g_{\mathrm{sqrt}}(n) = \lfloor \sqrt{n} \rfloor$.

Now iterate as follows, with $n = n_0$:

\begin{eqnarray}
n &=&  f^2_{\mathrm{next}}(n)\\
n &=& g_{\mathrm{sqrt}}(n)\\
n &=& n \pm 1 \;,
\end{eqnarray}
where $n$ is augmented in the last equation by $\{-1,1\}$ with equal probability.

So, for $n_0=20$, $f^2_{\mathrm{next}}(20)$ is $401$, the next prime after $20^2$, and then
$\lfloor \sqrt{401} \rfloor = 20$.
But then, the random $\pm 1$ leads to 
$\lfloor \sqrt{401} \rfloor -1  = 19$,
which leads to $f^2_{\mathrm{next}}(19)=$ the next prime after $361$,
which is $367$. Etc.
So in one random sequence, we see development like this:

---

[image]

---

So there is a push-forward toward the next prime by $f^2_{\mathrm{next}}(n)$,
counterbalanced by a fall-backward via the floor-function in $g_{\mathrm{sqrt}}(n)$,
and confused by the $\pm 1$.

> **Q**. What is the ultimate behavior of this sequence for a given $n_0$?

Comment: Legendre conjectured that there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$, and this is generally believed to be true.  Assuming this, for any $n$, $g(f(n))=n$, so you're just looking at a random walk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested, I am making my comment into an answer.

It is a conjecture of Legendre that there is always a prime between $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$.  According to Wikipedia, this has been checked for $n$ up to $10^{18}$, and it would follow from standard conjectures about the distribution of gaps between primes.  In particular, Legendre's conjecture is roughly equivalent to knowing that $p_{n+1}-p_n \leq 2 \sqrt{p_n}$ for all $n$.  The best results we have toward this are due to Baker, Harman, and Pintz, who have shown that $p_{n+1}-p_n \ll p_n^{0.525}$, and it's a conjecture of Cramer that $p_{n+1}-p_n \ll \log^2 p_n$ for all $n$ and that this is sharp (i.e., the limsup of the ratio exists and is positive).

At any rate, assume Legendre's conjecture is true.  We then have, for any $n\geq 1$, that $g_{\mathrm{sqrt}}(f^2_\mathrm{next}(n))=n$, and we also visibly have $g_{\mathrm{sqrt}}(f^2_{\mathrm{next}}(0))=1$.  Thus, everything interesting is happening with the $\pm 1$ factor in the final step of the iteration, and so we're just looking at a random walk that is not permitted to go below 0.